# How can I get a method to throw a custom exception I've created?

Tags: java, exception

So my custom exception is `PatternFormatException`, and I've appended `throws PatternFormatException`, to the end of my method, but I'm wondering how I can actually get the method to physically throw it? Do I use `if statements`? i.e.

```
  if //[doesn't_parse] throw PatternFormatException
```

This seems cumbersome for many different lines of code? Can I catch a more universal in built exception i.e. `NumberFormatException`, and then in the handling of this, throw my own exception?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just do it and see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You throw an exception using the `throw` keyword:

`throw new PatternFormatException(...);`

Generally you want to catch exceptions as early as they occur and handle them properly. If you want your parser (or whatever program you are writing) to generate meaningful errors, it's usually a good idea to wrap any caught exception and re-throw it, embedded in a more meaningful exception, giving the user a better idea of how things went wrong.

Something like this:

```
try {
  doSomething();  // throws SomeException
  doSomethingElse();  // throws SomeOtherException
}
catch (Exception e) {
  throw new PatternFormatException(..., e);
}
```

generally is fine, if you know exactly what exceptions might happen and if all of them are properly encapsulated by `PatternFormatException`. However, the key idea of Exceptions in Java is that you are always aware of all the possible Exceptions that can happen. That is why Java forces you to add all possibly thrown Exceptions (except for [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)) to the method declaration.

A safer design would be:

```
try {
  doSomething();  // throws SomeException
  doSomethingElse();  // throws SomeOtherException
}
catch (SomeException e) {
  throw new PatternFormatException(..., e);
}
catch (SomeOtherException e2) {
  throw new PatternFormatException(..., e2);
}
catch (Exception e3) {
  throw new UnexpectedPatternFormatException(..., e3);
}
```

Note that the first two `catch`es call different constructors, and thus can handle different Exceptions differently. The last `catch` wraps an *unexpected* exception because your program encountered an exception (probably a `RuntimeException`) that you did not plan for. If users then complain about `UnexpectedPatternFormatException`, you can just go back to your code and fix the code so that the underlying Exception either does not get thrown anymore or gets wrapped in a more meaningful way. You can also just use a single `UnexpectedMySomethingException` class as the fall-back for all try/catch blocks that you have, to keep things a bit simpler.

One last word should be said about issues caused by Exceptions: Even though, Java uses Exceptions for all kinds of situations, even those that are largely not in the control of the Java programmer (e.g. when accessing files or even trying to parse strings as numbers), always be aware that throwing and catching Exceptions is actually quite expensive, which is why many people tend to avoid that. Only really use Exceptions, if performance is not of an issue (when the Exception is a rare event).

Also, Exceptions can threaten the integrity of your program's state if you throw an Exception and catch it too late, so that lines that should have been executed did not get executed (e.g. code for cleaning up resources or other code that is needed to keep the program state "correct"), and, as a result, the only safe thing to do is to shut down the program.

Comment: This is perfect, very concise. One thing, would I then catch the PatternFormatException under all the catches previously written above? And can I catch individual Exception objects, or only the general class?

Comment: You usually catch the `PatternFormatException` at the entry point of the "big routine" that calls this code and is publicly exposed. Unless this Exception does not provide enough information for the external user to really understand what is going on. Then you catch it internally and re-throw it again as part of something bigger (e.g. `ParserException`). Not sure what you mean by "catching individual Exception objects"? But it sounds like exactly what `catch` does.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you could just do this:

```
If(somethingBad){
  throw new PatternFormatException();
}
```

As stated in a response below.  If your going to check this exception over and over again you might want some Static Method/Class Method (use your programming brain).  For example you could do something like:

```
void checkForException(String pattern, String check){
    If(!check.equals(pattern)){
      throw new PatternFormatException();
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is:

```
try{
    checkForException("abc","123");
}catch(PatternFormatException pfe){
   System.out.println(pfe);  //Whatever you want to happen if the exception is thrown
}
```

Remember though, ONLY use exceptions for exceptional situations...

Have a read over this [for more information on exceptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html).  I find that I next to never use exceptions.

Comment: You understand correctly, I thought I could do this, however if I have lots of similar lines of code, i.e. a constructor which initialises lots of variables, and a lot of them which produce the same bad thing, this seems inefficient. Can I do it a better way?

Comment: @AlexLipp  I will have to come back to this a little later on as duty calls but...  I will add to my question.  The answer from Domi captures some of what I want to say.  Read over that link I posted and over what Domi had to say.

Comment: @AlexLipp Assuming they have lots of similar lines of code then all that can be encapsulated in a single method (which you should be doing anyway) then that method is the one that does the throwing and the rest just pass it up the stack